# Forcing ArcMap to name all geometry fields as SHAPE_Length or SHAPE_Area in file geodatabase?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geometry, esri-geodatabase, arcgis-10.4

I'm working with the model builder in ArcMap 10.4.1 and I need to do some geometry calculation using the fields ArcMap creates. I am doing this with the tool 'calculate field' and my expression is:

> ```
> [SHAPE_Length] / [SHAPE_Area]
> ```

But some of my feature classes have the geometry fields named as SHAPE_Length and SHAPE_Area and other feature classes as GEOM_LENGTH and GEOM_AREA. Because of the different names I cannot use an iterator to go through all my different feature classes because it will give an error when the geometry is stored as GEOM_Length rather then SHAPE_Length. Arcmap keeps naming the geometry field as GEOM_Length as in the original feature class even after altering the data or making a copy. I am working from a file geodatabase.

How can I force Arcmap to name all the geometry fields in the same way?

Comment: Is there a SHAPE field? Or is this different too?

Comment: That is also called GEOM* instead of SHAPE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an [UpdateCursor](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/updatecursor-class.htm) instead of Field Calculator but it will require som python coding. With the cursor you can use tokens for the geometry fields, for example SHAPE@AREA and SHAPE@LENGTH. This will work on all inputs.

For example code below will calculate the existing field 'LengthDividedByArea':

```
import arcpy

feature=r'C:\path\to\data.gdb\polygon'

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(feature,['SHAPE@AREA','SHAPE@LENGTH','LengthDividedByArea']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[2]=row[1]/row[0] #'LengthDividedByArea'='SHAPE@LENGTH'/'SHAPE@AREA'
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

You can execute the code in the [Python window](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/executing-tools/what-is-the-python-window-.htm) or add to a Modelbuilder model: [Integrating scripts within a model](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/integrating-scripts-within-a-model.htm)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The feature class I am doing the calculation on is actually created in the model. Will I be able to use this script in my spatial model? I'm not exactly python hero but I can do some very (very) basic scripting.

Comment: Thank you so much, that makes my model work. I have noticed that when I do an intersect with a layer that does use SHAPE as field names the new layer also uses SHAPE instead of GEOM. But why Arcmap uses different names for geometry fields is still a bit of a mistery...

Answer (score 0):

Found another solution, which isn't very efficient but does do the trick.

If another dataset does display geometry fields as SHAPE you can perform an [intersect](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/intersect.htm) with this layer. Make sure the layer with 'SHAPE' is the first input. The dataset that is created will copy the geometry fields from the first input layer.